# Data Table Tool table not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to export the datatable contents but it isnt working. Please help me on this.

```
 $('#myTable').dataTable({
     "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
     "oTableTools": {
         "sSwfPath": "../../js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
         "aButtons": [{
             "sExtends": "csv",
             "sButtonText": "Save to CSV"
         }]
      },
  })
```

Comment: What happens? What should happen? Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: I am not getting any errors

Comment: Do you see the buttons to export the table? Please provide more details, we can't help with such a poor description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this code and it working well :

```
          $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "sDom": "T<'clear'><'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "aaSorting": []

        });
```

You have any errors in the browser console? it can help maybe it doesnt find your swf.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing this

```
"oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                      "copy",
                      "csv",
                      "xls",
                      "print"
                ]
              },
```

Change buttons to default one and try.